# ffmpeg combining multiple commands into one

Tags: ffmpeg

Justing wondering how to combine below commands into one, I have searched how to combine simple filters with comma and complex filter with colon, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Basically I want the output of the first command to be the input of the second.

Command 1: concatenate multiple clips into one with different xfade transitions.

Command 2: add a fade in for a video

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4 -i input4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.500:offset=27.486[v01];[v01][2:v]xfade=transition=fadeblack:duration=1.000:offset=31.531[v02];[v02][3:v]xfade=transition=fadeblack:duration=1.000:offset=42.972[v03];[v03][4:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.500:offset=94.149,format=yuv420p[video];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.500:c1=tri:c2=tri[a01];[a01][2:a]acrossfade=d=1.000:c1=tri:c2=tri[a02];[a02][3:a]acrossfade=d=1.000:c1=tri:c2=tri[a03];[a03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.500:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map [video] -map [audio] -movflags +faststart output.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "fade=t=in:st=0.000:d=1.000:color=black" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4 -i input4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.500:offset=27.486[v01];[v01][2:v]xfade=transition=fadeblack:duration=1.000:offset=31.531[v02];[v02][3:v]xfade=transition=fadeblack:duration=1.000:offset=42.972[v03];[v03][4:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.500:offset=94.149,format=yuv420p,fade=t=in:st=0.000:d=1.000:color=black[video];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.500:c1=tri:c2=tri[a01];[a01][2:a]acrossfade=d=1.000:c1=tri:c2=tri[a02];[a02][3:a]acrossfade=d=1.000:c1=tri:c2=tri[a03];[a03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.500:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map [video] -map [audio] -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```